# Take out repeated rows based on two columns of criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search for duplicates in two corresponding columns in excel and pull those rows. For example if cell W1 matches Cell W3 I would only pull that row if cell Y1 matches Cell Y3 as well. The code below is the best way I have come up with to accomplish this comparison. However, with 200000+ line items the code takes a long time to run. Is there a more efficient way?

```
match_formula = "MATCH(W" & i & "&Y" & i & ",$W$" & i + 1 & ":$W$" & LastCell & _
"&$Y$" & i + 1 & ":$Y$" & LastCell & ",0)"

result = Evaluate(match_formula)
```

My issue is I have to run through this code 200k+ times which is time consuming. 
Thank you ahead for any help

Comment: The problem here is that you scan the entire list for each item in the list. Since you've got 200.000 items, it is going to take a while. Can you provide a bit more clarity on what you're trying to achieve? The conditions on when you want to retrieve a row are still a bit hazy to me.

Comment: Possibly fastest way to do this is first sort the list with some algorithm like QuickSort and remove the lines after this. That way when going trough the data you will skip few steps of every time looping all values. You only need to check if next cell is equal etc.

Comment: Oh, and to be frank, this is fairly easy to do with excels remove duplicates on data ribbon .. Just add one column where you combine data on col W & Y and use that column as the criteria..

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It isn't quite as easy as just removing the rows though. I have to pull a row based off the criteria above (two columns have to have matching values in the same rows). When I pull the row I place it in a new corresponding spreadsheet based off of a different column. Right now I am only looking at the values below the items I look at. This way the system doesn't have to check 200k + items every time. My logic is if the item above one doesn't find a match it would waste time to have items below search the entire document.

Comment: Ex. If A1 and A4 both have the value 65 and D1 and D4 both have the value 90 I could pull this row and sort it into a new document based on a third column I have.

If A1 and A4 have the value 60, but D1 is 32 and D4 is 20 I would not pull this row. Hope this clears things up a little

Comment: Ok, then you just need to sort the data and do the copy for the rows that meet the criteria before you delete them.. Should be pretty straight forward, unless there is a specific reason for not to sort the data, but even then you can just read the data and row number to array and sort the array, and based on the array just copy and remove wanted values..